# Grails - Hibernate - cannot create model class / table

Tags: java, hibernate, grails

i have  Grails(2.2.1) project and want to with Hibernate create simple "model" class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="User")
class User {

    static mapping = {
        datasource 'system'
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="id")
    private Long userId;

    @Column(name="email", nullable=false)
    private String email;

    public User(){

    }

    @Transient
    public Long getUserId(){
        return this.userId;
    }

    @Transient
    public String getEmail(){
        return this.email;
    }

}
```

but i getting this follow error :

```
Caused by MappingException: Could not determine type for: org.springframework.validation.Errors, at table: user, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(errors)]
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
```

When i remove all hibernate annotations, app is deployed on server but table User has only two attributes (id, version).

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Small question: why Hibernate, and not just a 'plain' domain object?

Comment: I am used to work with hibernate (from other projects), now i have project in grails - so i am wondering it its possible to "bind grails and hibernate"

Comment: Not sure what you mean here. Grails uses Hibernate under the hood, so it's already 'bound'. If you create a User class in the 'grails-app/domain' dir, it will be persistent automatically using Hibernate.

Comment: Problem is "almost" solved.

I was creating my domain classes in "grails domain" folder. When i moved them into "standart" folder for java classes, app was successfully builded / deployed.

Hibernate just not create table in database - but this will be just matter of datasources (during deploying hibernate is trying to create table from logs, but its not successfull).

Comment: You need to go through this [page](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/hibernate.html). in short, you need `hibernate.cfg.xml` as well. I second @ErikPragt on using domain classes if feasible. Getting acquainted with it will help you in longer run. *Come out of the discomfort zone to the bliss of Grails and GORM*. That is why we say "The search is over" when you use Grails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your domain class to `grails-app/domain` and change it to this:

```
class User {
    String email

    static mapping = {
        datasource 'system'
    }

    static constraints = {
        email nullable: false
    }
}
```

11 lines vs. 31 lines. Groovy.